# error: no commands supplied when trying to import python library

Tags: python, runtime-error

I just installed the library Pyunicorn, which apparently went well. Then when I import it or run a script that imports it, I get the following error:

```
usage:  [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or:  --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or:  --help-commands
   or:  cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the file `__init__` in the `pyunicorn` library. There there is a line `from setup import __version__` which gives a bug. It should be erased!

Once this line is erased it is gonna work.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2283) to the bug.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `pyunicorn` is supposed to be run from the command line as a command, not imported as a module. Sometimes people put applications on PyPI (run) and don't differentiate them from modules (imported).

Comment: However, I use this library in another environment and there I import it.